# Add new shortcut in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Can we add a new shortcut in Android Studio?

For example we can do this:

```
sout (+TAB) ==> System.out.println();
```

And i want to add a new one, e.g:

```
soutc (+TAB) ==> System.out.println("my own format: ");
```

Am I able to do that in AS?

Answer (score 0):

These are called Live Templates. To edit a template or add a new one, go to File -> Settings -> Live Templates in the menu. Alternatively, press Shift-Ctrl-A, type Live Templates, and press Enter.

Answer (score -1):

You can [Configure Custom Keymaps](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts.html#configure_custom_keymaps) if you want to add your own shortcuts, as explained in the linked documentation. It is under `File -> Settings -> Keymap` or `File -> Properties -> Keymap` on Mac OS.

After adding a new shortcut or selecting a previous one, you can edit the Action related to that shortcut according to your needs.